# Load operation failed after selecting a new table - works again after unselect

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am currently facing a really strange problem with Visual Studio LightSwitch 2010 in combination with an Oracle Database and ODP.NET.

So far I have added all the necessary tables to the LightSwitch application and also created the screens for all the tables - it worked as it should.

Then I added / selected a new table - let us call it `errorcodes` - from the Oracle database and ran into problems. As long as I let the `errorcodes` table selected I always get the error message:

> Load operation failed for query 'dtFacilities_All'. The remote server
>   returned an error: NotFound.

The funny thing about that is, that `dtFacilities_All` worked all the time **before** I selected the new table. The screen for the facilities is the first screen when you start the application - if I select another first screen I get the same error with the table of the new start screen.

When I un-select the `errorcodes` table everything runs fine again. It seems it has something to do with the `errorcodes` table itself - but I don't know what.

The table `errorcodes` has a primary key set so this can not be the problem.

I hope someone can help me.

*Stacktrace*

```
    {System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.LightSwitch.ClientGenerated.Implementation.DomainContextClient.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update on this:

The table `errorcodes` contains a column called ISLOSS. The column is type of `NUMBER(1,0)` - LightSwitch maps it in the entity correctly as an bool value. When i change the datatype of that column to `NUMBER(2,0)` everything works fine.

It seems that lightswitch has an problem with this datatype (`NUMBER(1,0)`). But i really don't know how to solve it - changing the datatype to `NUMBER(2,0)` is just a temp. workaround..